# Read HDFS file in Spark Application in Kerberized Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, kerberos, keytab

I setup a Hadoop Cluster with Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5, which also includes Ambari 2.4, Kerberos, Spark 1.6.2 and HDFS.

I have e.g. the Kerberos principals and keytabs for the following users:

- spark (created by Ambari during Kerberos enabling)
- hdfsuserA (created by kadmin -> add_principle)

User `spark` is needed to run the `spark-submit` command in the secured cluster, and the Spark application must open some files in HDFS directory `/user/hdfsuserA/...` , which is owned by the hdfsuserA (700).

Since I enabled Kerberos, my Spark application won't run anymore, it fails with the following exception

```
[Stage 1:>     (0 + 92) / 162]Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 55 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 55.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 225, had-data1): org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=spark, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/hdfsuserA/new/data/Export_PDM_Hadoop_05_2016.csv":hdfsuserA:hadoop:drwx------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1827)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPathAccess(FSDirectory.java:1785)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1862)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1831)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1744)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307)
```

The issue is, that I authenticate with user `spark` to be able to start the Spark application, but inside the app, I get an exception as the `/user/hdfsuserA` HDFS directory is not accessable by the spark user.

When I run the spark-submit command with user `hdfsuserA` I get:

```
[hdfsuserA@had-job ~]$ kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hdfsuserA.keytab hdfsuserA

[hdfsuserA@had-job ~]$ spark-submit --class spark.sales.TestAnalysis --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/hdfsuserA/application_new.jar hdfs://had-job:8020/user/hdfsuserA/new/data/*
16/12/03 09:44:46 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/12/03 09:44:46 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@141.79.71.34:46996]
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead is set but does not apply in client mode.
spark.driver.cores is set but does not apply in client mode.
16/12/03 09:44:49 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://had-job:9083
16/12/03 09:44:49 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
        at myutil.SparkContextFactory.createSparkContext(SparkContextFactory.java:34)
        at spark.sales.BasketBasedSalesAnalysis.main(BasketBasedSalesAnalysis.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What is the correct solution for such an issue? Can I e.g. `kinit` for another user inside the app?

Comment: Either the spark user needs access to the files or you need to run the app as hdfsuserA. Why can't you run spark-submit from all users?

Comment: I aways was able to run the spark-submit script before I enabled Kerberos. I'm wondering why this doesn't work anymore since kerberizing the cluster?

Comment: What error do you get when you run as hdfsuserA?

Comment: Your hint was very helpful: I only created the "hdfsuserA" user on the NameNode host of my cluster. Creating the user on all hosts solved the problem, see my answer below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: It was an user issue! As I only created the `hdfsuserA` on the NameNode host of my cluster from where I run the `spark-submit` command, the application was not able to authenticate as this user via keytabs on the other hosts.

So to solve this issue: Add the same user on **all hosts of the cluster**:

```
sudo useradd hdfsuserA
sudo passwd hdfsuserA
```

Calling the spark application should work afterwards (with `master yarn` parameter in `spark-submit`, with `master local[x]` it always worked)!